# Can I instantiate a type as 'dynamic' from another AppDomain?

Tags: c#, dynamic, appdomain

I'm trying to load a type from a different assembly (not known at build time) as 'dynamic' and execute a method on that type. My goal is to completely disconnect the 'plugin' from the parent application such that there is no requirement for any shared code or common interface type. The interface is implied by way of an expected method signature on the loaded type.

This works:

```
dynamic myObj = Assembly.Load("MyAssembly").CreateInstance("MyType");
myObj.Execute();
```

However this will load the type into the current AppDomain along with all its dependent assemblies.
I want to modify this to allow me to do that same thing in a separate AppDomain.

This works but doesn't make use of the dynamic keyword, I need to know the explicit type that I am instantiating to be able to call the Execute method:

```
var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(domainName, evidence, setup);
var myObj = appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(assembly, type);
typeof(IMyInterface).InvokeMember("Execute",  BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, myObj);
```

This is essentially my target case and I have been trying to get something like this working:

```
dynamic myObj = ad.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(assembly, type);
myObj.Execute();
```

I keep ending up with a RuntimeBinderException with the message "'System.MarshalByRefObject' does not contain a definition for 'Execute'". This message makes sense, sure it doesn't contain a definition for 'Execute', but I know the type that I am instantiating does indeed contain an 'Execute' method. I imagine there's something going on here with the transparent proxy that is preventing this from working but I'm not sure what.

My actual class that I am trying to instantiate looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass : MarshalByRefObject {
  public void Execute() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

I have also tried this with a shared interface (not my primary goal, but I'm trying to figure this out first) so it would look like:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass : MarshalByRefObject, IPlugin {
  public void Execute() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Where IPlugin is a known type in the parent application and the plugin has the appropriate reference at build time but this doesn't seem to work either.

I'm guessing at this point that it's not possible to load a type as dynamic across the AppDomain boundary.

Is there a way to actually get this to work?

Comment: You will have to implement `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` IIRC (basically a wrapper around the remote object)

Comment: Why are you placing `Serializable` on a `MarshalByRefObject`?  That's an oxymoron in this case and affects how the instance is remoted.

Comment: @casperOne Serializable attribute is on MarshalByRefObject anyway so I agree it may be redundant, I don't think saying it's an oxymoron is correct. I'm not familiar with how this would affect the remoted instance, but I've removed the Serializable attribute and it is the exact same result.

Comment: @ChrisStavropoulos Sorry, I wasn't indicating as a means of solving your problem.  For your *actual* problem, you'd want to create a wrapper that implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` (as [leppie said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213922/can-i-instantiate-a-type-as-dynamic-from-another-appdomain#comment14725171_11213922)) but you'd have the implementation route to the [`RemotingServices.ExecuteMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.remotingservices.executemessage) method, which would then execute the call.

Comment: @ChrisStavropoulos You'd have to construct the [`IMethodCallInterface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.imethodcallmessage) interface, though, which is not a trivial task (and I'm not sure if an out-of-the-box implementation exists already).

Comment: @casperOne Is this even worth the effort then? The only reason I was going down this road was to avoid nightmare scenarios of updating a common interface assembly and breaking compatibility between a parent application and its plugins. From a purely educational perspective it will be enjoyable to dig into this but from a getting things done perspective, is it worth it?

Comment: @ChrisStavropoulos From my perspective, it's not.  Let's say you change the signature of one of the methods, or add a new method, you still have to recompile and redistribute both the client and the server, and on top of that, you won't get any compile-time checks that your call is correct (with dynamic, it's evaluated at run-time).  Because of that, I'd say have a separate assembly with *just* the interface contract, and then cast your proxies to that.  It makes life much simpler.

Comment: @casperOne I am familiar with the benefits of an actual interface and I generally go out of my way to promote the benefits of type-safety. My concern with this particular case was more geared towards dealing with assembly versioning issues with the interface-only assembly. But I guess as long as I can restrict changes to be additive only, that probably won't be a huge deal. I appreciate the feedback, how do I go about marking an 'answer' for this question?

Comment: @ChrisStavropoulos I'll summarize in the contents in an answer and then you can accept that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [leppie indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213922/can-i-instantiate-a-type-as-dynamic-from-another-appdomain#comment14725171_11213922), you'll have to implement the [`IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider.aspx) to wrap the proxy that's being returned to you, and then you can use make `dynamic` calls on *that*.

In your implementation, you'd want to take the wrapped proxy and forward all calls to the static [`ExecuteMessage` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.remotingservices.executemessage) on the [`RemotingServices` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.remotingservices.aspx), which will take your proxy, as well as an [`IMethodCallMessage` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.imethodcallmessage) implementation.

Note that implementing the `IMethodCallMessage` interface is not trivial.  Also, you'd have to properly interpret the [`IMethodReturnMessage` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.imethodreturnmessage%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) implementation to get the return value, `ref` and `out` parameters correctly (if any).

That said, it's generally a better idea to provide an assembly that contains *only* an interface for the client and server to assume; if a method is changed in any way on the server side, even though the client side uses `dynamic`, you'd *still* have to change the call site to accommodate the change.  At least with the interface, you get *some* type of compile-time check, which is always preferred to a run-time error.